# Apply Mode for Filtered Results

Tags: excel

I'm trying to set up a Mode formula that only uses the filtered results of a table and can be updated depending on the filter.

Currently I have

> =INDEX([Column7],MODE(MATCH([Column7],[Column7],0)))

however this unfortunately also includes the hidden data.

The formula is meant to reflect the most frequent text within a range.

What would be the best approach to this?

Thanks for your help!

Francis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `SUBTOTAL` and `OFFSET` to only reference the visible values, like this:

`=INDEX([Column7],MODE(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET([Column7],ROW([Column7])-MIN(ROW([Column7])),0,1)),MATCH([Column7],[Column7],0))))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This version may be more "copyable"

`=INDEX(D2:D20,MODE(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(D2:D20,ROW(D2:D20)-MIN(ROW(D2:D20)),0,1)),MATCH(D2:D20,D2:D20,0))))`

see screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Barry, I appreciate your help! I copy and pasted your example to test it out but get '#VALUE!'. Keep in mind, the formula is intended to be used for cells containing alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Yeah - my suggestion should work for text values, I pasted it here, but when I copy it back to my test sheet now it doesn't work......! It may not like the square brackets, I used another version with a specific cell range like `D2:D20` - can you try that or replace the range with whatever you need

Comment: Sorry, I might be missing something. I tried this '=INDEX(G3:G86,MODE(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(G3:G86,ROW(G3:G86)-MIN(ROW(G3:G86)),0,1)),MATCH(G3:G86,G3:G86,0))))' and unfortunately still get the error.

Comment: That works for me - are you using `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`? What error do you get?

Comment: Oh, I apologize! I missed the 'CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER' part. It works now! :) Thanks heaps!